# Caused by: com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: ReferenceError: "XMLHttpRequest" is not defined Exception in Karate config js file

Tags: javascript, java, karate

I want to load my configurations from server but when I am doing using

XMLHttpRequest I  am getting Exception

> ava.lang.RuntimeException: evaluation of 'karate-config.js' failed
>           at com.intuit.karate.ScenarioContext.(ScenarioContext.java:211)
>           at com.intuit.karate.StepActions.(StepActions.java:50)
>           at com.intuit.karate.core.FeatureExecutionUnit.submit(FeatureExecutionUnit.java:85)
>           at com.intuit.karate.cucumber.CucumberRunner.callAsync(CucumberRunner.java:191)
>           at com.intuit.karate.gatling.KarateAction.execute(KarateAction.scala:62)
>           at io.gatling.core.action.Action.$bang(Action.scala:35)
>           at io.gatling.core.action.Action.$bang$(Action.scala:35)
>           at com.intuit.karate.gatling.KarateAction.io$gatling$core$action$ChainableAction$$super$$bang(KarateAction.scala:26)
>           at io.gatling.core.action.ChainableAction.$bang(Action.scala:60)
>           at io.gatling.core.action.ChainableAction.$bang$(Action.scala:58)
>           at com.intuit.karate.gatling.KarateAction.io$gatling$core$action$ExitableAction$$super$$bang(KarateAction.scala:26)
>           at io.gatling.core.action.ExitableAction.$bang(BlockExit.scala:137)
>           at io.gatling.core.action.ExitableAction.$bang$(BlockExit.scala:135)
>           at com.intuit.karate.gatling.KarateAction.$bang(KarateAction.scala:26)
>           at io.gatling.core.controller.inject.Injector.startUser(Injector.scala:130)
>           at io.gatling.core.controller.inject.Injector.injectUser(Injector.scala:140)
>           at io.gatling.core.controller.inject.Injector.$anonfun$injectStreams$2(Injector.scala:120)
>           at io.gatling.core.controller.inject.Injector.$anonfun$injectStreams$2$adapted(Injector.scala:120)
>           at io.gatling.core.controller.inject.UserStream.withStream(Injector.scala:61)
>           at io.gatling.core.controller.inject.Injector.$anonfun$injectStreams$1(Injector.scala:120)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>           at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:929)
>           at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:929)
>           at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1417)
>           at scala.collection.MapLike$DefaultValuesIterable.foreach(MapLike.scala:210)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>           at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:227)
>           at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
>           at io.gatling.core.controller.inject.Injector.injectStreams(Injector.scala:120)
>           at io.gatling.core.controller.inject.Injector.io$gatling$core$controller$inject$Injector$$inject(Injector.scala:106)
>           at io.gatling.core.controller.inject.Injector$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(Injector.scala:151)
>           at io.gatling.core.controller.inject.Injector$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(Injector.scala:148)
>           at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:34)
>           at akka.actor.FSM.processEvent(FSM.scala:665)
>           at akka.actor.FSM.processEvent$(FSM.scala:662)
>           at io.gatling.core.controller.inject.InjectorFSM.processEvent(InjectorFSM.scala:34)
>           at akka.actor.FSM.akka$actor$FSM$$processMsg(FSM.scala:659)
>           at akka.actor.FSM$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(FSM.scala:653)
>           at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:514)
>           at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:512)
>           at io.gatling.core.akka.BaseActor.aroundReceive(BaseActor.scala:23)
>           at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:527)
>           at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:496)
>           at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
>           at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
>           at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
>           at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>           at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>           at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>           at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
>   Caused by: com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: javascript
>   function call failed: ReferenceError: "XMLHttpRequest" is not defined
>           at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalFunctionCall(Script.java:1636)
>           at com.intuit.karate.Script.call(Script.java:1587)
>           at com.intuit.karate.Script.callAndUpdateConfigAndAlsoVarsIfMapReturned(Script.java:1709)
>           at com.intuit.karate.ScenarioContext.(ScenarioContext.java:206)

---

My config File Code :

```html
function () {
    var System = Java.type('java.lang.System');
    var env = System.getProperty("profile");
    if (!env) {
        karate.log('env is not defined.')
        env = 'dev';
    }
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "http://www.testsite.com",false);
    request.send();
    var result = request.responseText;
    console.log(result);
    return result
}
```

Comment: Are you programming in *Java* or in *JavaScript*? Those are two completely unrelated (and incompatible!) languages, but it looks like you've got both of them in this one file.

Comment: I am using karate with gatling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Sorry, that's not going to work. Karate supports just ES2015 and plain JS.

Also:

```
request.open("GET", "http://www.testsite.com",false);
```

That's totally un-necessary, since Karate's speciality is making HTTP requests ! Please read the docs more carefully. For example you can do this in a `*.feature` file:

```
Feature:

Scenario:
Given url 'http://www.testsite.com'
When method get
Then status 200
And def result = response
And print result
```

And are you sure you have to do this in `karate-config.js` ? Sounds like you are completely new to Karate - but if so, you can do: `var result = karate.call('my.feature');`.

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same issue.
Because I want to send notice when Scenario execute failed, like this:

```
Feature:

  Background:
    * url baseApi
    * configure afterScenario =
    """
    function() {
      if (karate.info.errorMessage != null) {
        callback();
      }
    }
    """
    * configure retry = { count: 3, interval: 3000 }

  Scenario: get it (ERROR)
    * def input =
    """
    {
      'form': {
        'id': '123509638998',
        'td': '5xm6ksy6ty2jqam',
        'nd': '0'
      },
      'query': {
      }
    }
    """
    * path '/rest/n/list'
    * params input.query
    * form fields input.form
    * retry until responseStatus == 200
    * method post
    * match response contains { result: 1 }
```

And `karate-config.js` like this:

```
function() {
  karate.configure('connectTimeout', 5000);
  karate.configure('readTimeout', 5000);
  var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8088';
  if (karate.properties['apiServer'] != '') {
    url = karate.properties['apiServer'];
  }

  var config = {
    apiBaseUrl: url,
    callback: function() {
      var url = 'https://x.y.z.com/api/send?access_token=257def70cab07fda4e93efeae04c497d';

      var data = JSON.stringify({
        'id': '123',
        'msgtype': 'text',
        'text':{
          'content': 'Test message...'
        }
      });

      fetch(url, {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" },
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
      })
    }
  };

  return config;
}
```